# ASP.NET GridView Model-binding

Tags: asp.net, gridview, model-binding

I am new to ASP.NET and I want to write a simple WebApplication  using WebForms that connects to a Database and displays some data in a Grid (with paging). I use Visual Studio 2015

For displaying the data I use a GridView in combination with an ObjectDataSource.

I use EntityFramework and a method GetCustomer() that returns all Customers from a database.I use that method as `SelectMethod`

My question is:
Both controls, GridView an ObjectDataSource, have parameters for `Paging and SelectMethod`

Which control’s parameter for Paging and SelectMethod should I use if I want to use `Model Binding`?

Currently I’m using this:

```
GridView :<br>

AllowPaging     = true<br>
PageSize    = 10<br>
SelectMethod    = ""<br>
DataSourceID    = dsCustomers<br>
```

```
ObjectDataSource:<br>
ID                  = dsCustomers<br>
EnablePaging        = false<br>
SelectMethod        = GetCustomers ()<br>
MaximumRowParameterName = ""<br>
StartRowIndexParameterName  = ""<br>
```

These settings work, the data is displyed and paging is working.
But I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

And if I change the settings for `Paging and SelectMethod`  like so

```
GridView: <br>
AllowPaging     = false<br>
PageSize        = ""<br>
SelectMethod    = GetCustomers()<br>
DataSourceID    = dsCustomers<br>


ObjectDataSource:<br>
ID                  = dsCustomers<br>
EnablePaging                = true<br>
SelectMethod                = <br>
MaximumRowParameterName     = ""<br>
StartRowIndexParameterName  = ""<br>
```

I get an error :

> DataSource or DataSourceID cannot be defined on 'gridViewCustomers'
>   when it uses model binding.

If I remove DataSourceID from the GridView then I get

> "A public method with the name 'GetCustomers' was either not found or
>   there were multiple methods with the same name"

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it in the first example is correct.

1. Paging - should be set on the GridView level, specifying whether it's allowed or not and how many rows to display (`PageSize`).
2. CRUD methods - `SelectMethod`, `InsertMethod` , `DeleteMethod` and `UpdateMethod` should be specified on the `ObjectDataSource`.If you change this to `SqlDataSource` you would need to change it on the `SqlDataSource` level, but then the property names are slightly different e.g `SelectCommand`, `InsertCommand` e.t.c

Note: the `EnablePaging` property of the `ObjectDataSource` could most definitely be configured to enable paging on the `GridView` but it's more complicated and in all the years I've worked with the `GridView` control I've never seen anyone do it that way. Nevertheless, if you're curious how it can be done have a look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.enablepaging(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thx for your answer
But I see many examples on the net that put the SelectMethod within the GridView
e.g http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/03/SelectMethod-in-asp-net-45-Model-binding.html

This is what confuses me... is there a best-practice about how to implement Model-binding with a GridView & DataSource ?

Comment: It all depends on what your requirement is.If you just need to bind some data ONLY to the gridview then go ahead and use the SelectMethod.But if you have a whole bunch of grids and other controls that should use the same datasource then use an ObjectDataSource or a SqlDataSource and set the select method on them.There's not right or wrong way to do this, it all depends on your requirements