# Effective way of displaying results of stored procedure with interactive button columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

Apologies if the title is vague - I will explain in as much detail as possible the problem.

I have an ASP.NET webpage which queries a TSQL database using a stored procedure, the query is run on Page_Load. The procedure returns a dataset (with ID column, RequestID). The contents are essentially a list of data-specific requests that need to be approved or rejected as exceptions to another workflow (not entirely relevant but may help explain my approach)

I'd like to display the results of this procedure in a grid (currently this is easy enough) however I'm running into problems when trying to add buttons that allow the user to interact with the data, e.g. I'd like 'Reject/Approve' buttons.

When one of these buttons is pressed the relevant stored procedure would be run, with the RequestID of the row pressed passed as a parameter. The idea is to have the stored procedure update an audit log and update the relevant tables accordingly (each request represent a complex data object spanning multiple tables) -  for this reason the default controls aren't sufficient for select/edit/delete.

I feel like I'm doing this entirely wrong from the basic approach, which is using a gridview and trying to add custom SelectMethod/DeleteMethod's. What would be a best practice approach for doing this?

EDIT*

Here is the data table and how i'm populating it:

```
DataTable Requests = new DataTable();
Requests = GetRequests(connString); //Method that returns a datatable from a stored procedure
```

Displaying the data in a gridview as follows:

```
gridView.DataSource = Requests;
gridView.DataBind();
```

However when i add the following code, which is me trying to fire a custom method when using the default select/delete controls in a gridview i get an exception:

```
gridView.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
gridView.AutoGenerateSelectButton = true;
gridView.SelectMethod = "ApproveRequest";
gridView.DeleteMethod = "RejectRequest";
```

Here is the exceptiopn (which make sense, but makes me think i'm going about this the wrong way).

```
Message=DataSource or DataSourceID cannot be defined on 'gridView' when it uses model binding.
```

Comment: ...Do you want to show us your code or...?

Comment: "the default controls aren't sufficient for select/edit/delete." What do you mean by this?

Comment: This may or may not help, but it could lead you in the right direction hopefully. 

[Cannot Be Defined On...When It Uses Model Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695988/asp-net-gridview-model-binding)

Comment: I scoured google for you and this is the only one with a similar error message. Hehe

Comment: I had the same issue looking in google. The error makes absolute sense - i believe i'm just trying to use the control in a way not intended, which is why i wanted some sanity checking and maybe someone who'd done something similar in the past to let me know what control/method they ended up using.

Comment: @NaN The reason I've said "the default controls aren't sufficient for select/edit/delete." is because the dataset i'm returning is just a representation of a much more complex object within the DB data-model. I can't select/edit/delete the results of this stored procedure, instead i need to pass the ID of the data object into a stored procedure to be processed by another part of the workflow.